# Github Pages with custom GitHub Action workflow is not using the right branch gh-pages

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I used to have Github pages running with source from `gh-pages` branch perfectly.

But, today something changed and it throws an Error:

```
Ensure GITHUB_TOKEN has permission "id-token: write".
```

So, to [Assign permission to jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs) I had to create a custom GitHub Actions workflow to publish Github pages. And, I followed next steps [Publishing with a custom GitHub Actions workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-with-a-custom-github-actions-workflow).

By default, it was created a file `.github/workflows/jekyll-gh-pages.yml` similar to that one provided in [starter-workflows/pages/jekyll-gh-pages.yml](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/jekyll-gh-pages.yml).

But now it is deploying from default branch rather than from `gh-pages` branch.

I have already changed line 7 of [starter-workflows/pages/jekyll-gh-pages.yml](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/jekyll-gh-pages.yml) to:

```yaml
on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the gh-pages branch
  push:
    branches: gh-pages
```

But, nothing has changed and it is still deploying from default branch.

How can I make `jekyll-gh-pages.yml` deploy from `gh-pages`?

Answer (score 0):

In the build job, the `checkout` step was missing `ref` to `gh-pages` branch:

```
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: gh-pages
```